# Delete a lot of rows using Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am developing an app tomanipulate the information inside Smartsheet, but I have an issue when deleting a large number of rows. Is there any way to clear a sheet using the API different from using the delete row request? The problem is that for a large number of rows I get this error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>\n<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity\nlimit for this server.<br />\n</p>\n</body></html>\n"
```

I understand what it means, so I am looking for a another way to accomplish the same result

Answer (score 2):

**Make Multiple Smaller Requests**

Instead of trying to delete every row in one call, try deleting them 100 (or more or less) at a time. I don't know what the limit is for what you're hitting, so the specific maximum you can do at a time might be significantly different than 100.

**Create A New Sheet**

Record the column information of the original sheet, create a new sheet with that column info, and continue your work in the new sheet. You could then either archive the original sheet or delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes, I took into consideration those solutions, just searching for something more efficient. The create new sheet solution doiesn't work for my requirements, y need to use a selected sheet and delete the information in it. And the part where I split the rows into several parts has a problem, the delete request is not synchronized with the code, and I can think in a way to create a dinamic cicle whit asynchronous actions inside.